# Auto-increment Id value on each new row in CSV file

Tags: python, python-2.7

Creating a Ticket booking system Academic project. Customer ID value oo1, oo2.. must be auto increment for each new row added in csv file.

Final output :
 cust_Id,name
001, ABc
002, def
...,ert
...,hjg
Auto-increment id

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and rephrase/edit your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@aniket -> Can you try something like this.
This is using a variable to increment after reading each row.

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('pyxl_input.xlsx')
sheet= wb['cust_data']
i=0
    for row in range(2,sheet.max_row+1):
        col1=sheet['A' + str(row)].value
        print(str(i) + col1)
        i=i+1
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct function for auto increment (unless it is a db) as such in python(in my knowledge). What you need to do is before writing a record to csv you need to handle increment yourself.

Thanks,
Ashish

Answer (score 0):

If it a fixed file. Just retrieve the max value of id and plus one each time, make sure do it synchronously to avoid 2 same id row. Or just build up sqlite (I guess you don't want to run a full rdbms) and export csv whenever you need it.